# Simplifying JS query from JSON API

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to display some data from a API, using similar to the below example.

I need to feed in data such as a Video ID from a CMS, which will then retrieve additional data from the API about the video.

The below example works, but I'm not sure I've written it in the best way - and I would like to be able to set a variable using a Video ID from the CMS's front end template string. Below I am having to repeat the Video ID in order to get it to work - and I'm struggling to simplify this.

Any help appreciated!

```
async function getSomething() {
    let request = {
        item: {
            name: "example",
            colour: "red"
        },
        video: ["12345"]
    };
    let url = new URL("https://example.com"); 
    url.searchParams.append('data', JSON.stringify(request));
    let response = await fetch(url);
    let data = await response.json();
    console.log(data.video);
    return data;
}

getSomething().then(data => 
    document.querySelector('[data-video-id]').innerHTML = data.video.12345.label
);
```

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/